# Android app failure of execution in some devices

Tags: android, permissions, crash

In an [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nts.teacherassistant.trial) that I recently uploaded at Google Play there are reports of some users that the application can not even executed. In particular it is reported that this happens at

- Samsung S4
- LG Nexus 4
- Sony  Xperia  Z2
- Samsung Note 1 (N7000) (ANDROID 4.1.2)

The permissions of the app are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

A possible code incompatibility maybe is on the file functions since the application checks for a particular folder to exist every time that it executes and try to create it if it is not exist. However, since I do not have access at that devices, I can not be sure of anything.

So the question is:

Is there any particular restrictions on that devices concerning the permissions of the application? What could be the problems in the code that creates this problematic behaviour?

Thank you in advance for any hints or advices.

Comment: No problem in permissions. Can you provide the error? It may be happen for memory limit.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have error details, the users just tell me that the application does not start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at the third line of the MainActivity where I declared that the application will appear in landscape mode...

```
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

For a reason I do not understand that line created a memory overflow in some devices and the application was instantly crashed. I manage to find the faulty code by try and error when I created a Nexus 5 API 22 x86 virtual device and reproduce this situation.

The solution was to remove the above faulty line and type

```
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file.